# Nuxt Auth Module - save JWT in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

The login/logout/middleware etc themselves work, but I don't seem to have control over the token. I'm trying to save JWT in Vuex store after logging in, but the token is only saved in a cookie and localStorage. From documentation I understand that support for auth in Vuex is added automatically. I didn't define `tokenRequired` and `tokenType` in config as according to documentation they are needed for cookie based flow (also adding them did not change anything).

**nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
],
axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://api.example.com/'
},
router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
},
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
                logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
                user: false
            }
        }
    },
    redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        logout: '/',
        callback: '/login',
        home: '/'
    }
},
```

**login function**

```
await this.$axios.post('authenticate', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
}).then(response => {
    if (response.success === 'true') {
        this.$auth.setUserToken(response.token)
    } else {
        //alert invalid login
    }
}).catch(error => {
    //alert server error
});
```

Now when I successfully log in and look at **$auth.$state** it returns

```
{ "user": {}, "loggedIn": true, "strategy": "local" }
```

I expect the token to also be saved in `$auth`.

I also looked at a [question with similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986158/how-to-save-jwt-token-in-vuex-with-nuxt-auth-module), but their solution does not work for me, as I am using `user: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at auth-module's `default.js` file and tried the default values in my `nuxt.config.js`. After adding the default into my configuration it started working. So now I was able to disable the cookies and localStorage, while saving JWT into store only.

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
                logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
                user: false
            }
        }
    },
    redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        logout: '/',
        callback: '/login',
        home: '/'
    },
    cookie: false,
    localStorage: false,
    token: {
        prefix: 'token.'
    },
},
```

And `$auth.$state` returns

```
{ "user": {}, "loggedIn": true, "strategy": "local", "token.local": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c" }
```

If anyone has an explanation why the default value did not work and why I had to include it in my configuration, please let me know. I assume for some reason they have disabled the Vuex saving by default? Even though the documentation states what can be interpreted as by default token is saved in three locations.

> Auth tokens are stored in various storage providers (cookie, localStorage, vuex)